# Limit of $n$th root of $n$!

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, radicals

I am asked to determine if a series converges or not:

> $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^n)n!}{(n^n)}$$

So I'm using the $n$th root test and came up with $\lim_{n \to {\infty}}\frac{2}{n}\times(\sqrt[n]{n!})$
I know that the limit of $\frac{2}{n}$ goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity but what about the $(\sqrt[n]{n!})$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Stirling's Approximation? It claims that for large $n$, $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n} n^n$.

Comment: to be honest i don't know the stirling's approximation, I'm a college student majoring in physics and I'm taking Calculus III as a math course.

Comment: I would take a look in your text and see if they mention Stirling's Approximation in the relevant section. I cannot recall any other elementary ways to deal with the $n$th root of a factorial.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The Stirling's Approximation is not mentioned.

Comment: Stirling's approximation is overkill here.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476/

Comment: @MarwanNour In fact, if you have half an hour, you may sit down and write the Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+t)$ and $\ln(1-t)$ and calculate their difference $\frac12 \ln\frac{1+t}{1-t}$.  Then spend 15 minutes to [read a proof of this approximation](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/sequence/stirling/stirling.html).  Since then, you can save *hours* for limits involving factorials.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I will look into that. Thanks again

Comment: If you look at [frequent questions tagged limit+factorial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits+factorial?sort=frequent), you can find [$\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/136626) and [Calculating the limit $\lim((n!)^{1/n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/706461). (And also some of the questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/136626) might be of interest.)

Comment: And [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B2%5Enn!%7D%7Bn%5En%7D%24&p=1) you can also find some posts about the series mentioned in your question, for example, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931236/convergent-or-divergent-sum-k-1-infty-frac2k-cdot-kkk) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751275/simple-series-convergence-divergence).

Comment: Basically the situation with this post is that it contains three different questions. 
The title suggest that it is about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n!}$. 
However, in the body the OP asks about the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n$. And they ask about this limit because they are interested in $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^nn!}{n^n}$.
Whether this question is considered as a question about limit or about series, it seems that there are already duplicate questions where it was answered.

Comment: No need to yell when titling your question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since OP is taking Calculus III, perhaps the [ratio test from calculus II](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RatioTest.aspx) is a more suitable way.

Let $a_n = (2^n)n!/n^n$.

\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{(2^{n+1})(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}}{(2^n)n!/n^n} \\
&= 2(n+1) \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} \frac1{n+1} \\
&= 2 \frac1{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} \\
\end{align}

$$L = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} 2 \frac1{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} = \frac2e < 1 $$

So the series converges.

---

Alternative method by Stirling's approximation

I type this for fun and to show the power of this formula for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n n!}{n^n}$

Use the root test on $a_n = (2^n)n!/n^n$.

\begin{align}
a_n =& \frac{2^n n!}{n^n} \\
\sim& \frac{2^n\sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n} n^n}{n^n} \\
=& \sqrt{2\pi} \cdot \frac{2^n}{e^n} \cdot \sqrt{n}
\end{align}

The limit $1 \le \sqrt{n}^{1/n} \le n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to +\infty$ allows us to recover the ratio $2/e$ in the previous section.

$$L = \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} a_n^{1/n} = \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} \frac2e \sqrt{n}^{1/n} = \frac2e$$

Comment: @MarwanNour You're welcome.

Comment: Even replacing $i$ by $n$, the formulation $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n n!}{n^n}\sim\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^n)\sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n} n^n}{n^n}$$ is faulty and should read $$\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}\sim\frac{2^n\sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n} n^n}{n^n}$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for pointing out this logic error.  I've edited my post in response to your comment.  Since the convergence of the series is to be proved, this formulation is a flawed *argument*.

Comment: Perfect. (Any idea why two answers on this page are so massively upvoted?)

Comment: @Did For the other one, yes: his argument using Riemann sum is *so* beautiful and he makes use of elementary tools.  For mine, I have no idea.  I just type the second part for fun.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 You might add to the first methodology that for any non-negative sequence $a_n$ we have $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le  \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Answer (score 56):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on elementary tools only.  To that end, we now proceed.

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)&=\frac1n\log(n!)-\log(n)\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)-\log(n)\\\\
&=\underbrace{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)}_{\text{Riemann Sum for}\,\,\int_0^1 \log(x)\,dx=-1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)=2e^{-1}$$

And we are done!

> Tools Used.  Straightforward arithmetic and Riemann sums.

Comment: Short. Concise. Love it.

Comment: @gnusupporter Thank you.  Much appreciative!  -Mark

Comment: Upvoted for this brilliant proof, but please stop using citations to show emphasis,  for something that isn't quoted text.

Comment: @federicopoloni Thank you,  Much appreciative.  I don't know what you mean regarding citations to show emphasis.

Comment: See those lines with yellow background, that you produced by starting a line with `>`? That is semantic markup for citations, in Markdown. You are supposed to use them only when you are quoting text from someone else, not to make the sentence stand out.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Even site admin use `>` to highlight a sentence b/c it looks great.  For example, see [Tag management 2017](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25910/290189) on Meta Math.SE

Comment: @GNUSupporter "Even the admins do it" does not mean it's correct. We have had a similar discussion at academia.se: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2200/adding-emphasis-with-blockquotes

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I see your point.  You may start a post at meta math.se to raise the awareness of site admin.  That's more effective than saying this hundreds of times in a comment.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Done: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25939/stop-misuse-of-markdown-blockquotes-for-emphasis

Comment: @FedericoPoloni upvoted

Answer (score 9):

Note that we do not need to actually evaluate the limit, we just need to find an upper bound.

Consider that, for $n>m$,
$$
\frac{n!}{m!}\leq n^{n-m}
$$
As such, if we let $n=6k-a$, where $0\leq a\leq5$, we can observe that
$$
n!\leq (6k)!\leq \prod_{i=1}^6 (ik)^k=(720k^6)^k<\left
(\frac{20}{6^4}\right)^k(6k)^{6k}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sqrt[n]{n!}<\left(\frac{20}{6^4}\right)^{(n+a)/6n}(n+a)^{1+a/n}
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{2\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}<2\left(\frac{20}{6^4}\right)^{1/6}\left(\frac{20}{6^4}\right)^{a/6n}(1+a/n)(n+a)^{a/n}
$$
Now, as $a$ cannot be larger than 5, we can easily take the limit of each term as $n\to\infty$, to give
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}<2\left(\frac{20}{6^4}\right)^{1/6}\approx 0.997932
$$
Therefore, as the limit is less than 1, it converges.

Note that the $\lim$ in the final line isn't strictly correct notation, as we have not proven that the limit exists. That said, it captures the intent, that for sufficiently large $n$, the expression will be less than $0.997932$.

Comment: +1 for the upper bound to avoid limits involving $e$ and log.  At the 2nd step, it's $n! \le (6k)!$.

Comment: @Dr.MV - I didn't presume anything. Convergence isn't necessary, just that the $\limsup$ is less than 1 (and $\liminf$ isn't negative).

Comment: @GlenO Yes, but you wrote $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n!}}{n}<2(20/6^4)^6$.  If the limit fails to exist, then it does really make sense to write a bound.  You might consider writing $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$ here.  Anyway, I have up voted your answer.  So, well done.